# Does a pairing of sets contain the constituent sets' elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two sets

$$A=\{1,2,3\} \qquad \qquad B=\{4,5,6\}$$

We now define the set $C=\{A,B\}$. Are the elements of $A$ and $B$ now elements of $C$? Or are $A$ and $B$ the elements of the set? Put simply, is $2$ (for example) an element of the set $C$?

Comment: Apologies for the obvious question, I am trying to learn basic set theory and want to be absolutely sure on the axioms of such.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are sets of integers. $C$ is a **set of sets** of integers. Hence, the elements of $A$ and $B$ are not elements of $C$.

Comment: Fantastic thank you @RodrigodeAzevedo.

Comment: The elements of $C$ are simply $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @drhab I think you meant the naturals, not the integers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ah.. yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C contains just what you defined it to contain, A and B. It doesn't "care" what those things are, they might be sets, numbers or vectors. So 2 is not in C.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is an element of $C=\{A,B\}$ if and only if $x=A\vee x=B$.

So your last question (is $2$ an element of the set $C$?) can be refrased as:

> is it true that $2=A$ or that $2=B$?

In order to answer that question we must know how $2$ is defined. Commonly natural numbers are (inductively) defined by $n=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ and on base of that we can find that $2\notin C$.

---

Exercise.

Let it be that $D=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$.

Now we define the set $E:=\{D,B\}$.

Question: is $4$ (which is just like $2$ an element of $B$) an element of the set $E$?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, you have to distinguish between unions and pairing.
For your A and B,

A $\cup$ B = {1, 2, 3} $\cup$ {4, 5, 6} = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

The pair {A,B} is the set containing sets A, B as elements. Namely { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }